# How to split a list on the basis of an element in the list in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings like this: `[['ROOT', 'S'], ['S', 'NP', ')', 'VP', ')'], ['NP', 'DT', 'NN']]`.

I want that whenever a `')'` is encountered in the list, it should split it to another internal list, and instead of `')'`, add a `' '` to both the new lists formed. Like in the above example, there are 2 occurrences of `')'`, so I want the output to be like this:

```
[['ROOT', 'S'], ['S', 'NP', ' '], [' ', 'VP', ' '], [' '], ['NP', 'DT', 'NN']]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `list` to a `string`. Make **replacements** as you like. Then use `ast` package to convert that `string` back to **data structure** (list in this case) if the string is in proper format. Demo:

```
>>> import ast
>>> lst=[['ROOT', 'S'], ['S', 'NP', ')', 'VP', ')'], ['NP', 'DT', 'NN']]
>>> lst=str(lst)
>>> lst=lst.replace('\')\'','\' \'], [\' \'')
>>> lst=ast.literal_eval(lst)
>>> lst
[['ROOT', 'S'], ['S', 'NP', ' '], [' ', 'VP', ' '], [' '], ['NP', 'DT', 'NN']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [['ROOT', 'S'], ['S', 'NP', ')', 'VP', ')'], ['NP', 'DT', 'NN']]

answer = []
for subl in L:
    temp = []
    for elem in subl:
        if elem != ")":
            temp.append(elem)
            continue
        temp.append(' ')
        answer.append(temp)
        temp = [' ']
    answer.append(temp)
```

Output:

```
In [4]: answer
Out[4]: [['ROOT', 'S'], ['S', 'NP', ' '], [' ', 'VP', ' '], [' '], ['NP', 'DT', 'NN']]
```

Comment: might help if you wrote some comments and explained what is actually happening

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: that /would/ help. But I'm sick today (hence my minimal presence). Thought I could still help by providing /some/ code. Plus, all posts on SO are under creative commons, so I figured someone else might be able to contribute as well...